# Linq Expression: Perform Distinct on a list dynamic property

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-expressions

I've a list of objects on which I need to perform a Distinct() function. Currently I use the following code.

```
Return choices = displaylist
    .Select(Function(x) x.Zone)
    .ToList
    .Distinct()
```

The above code works well for me. However I need to expand this code into something that allows me to provide any property name and return me the distinct values of the list. My custom object has 20+ properties e.g. Zone, Region, Department, etc.

I need to make a flexible function that I give any property name and it returns distinct. Something like this pseudo:

```
Function GetDistincts(PROPERTYNAME as string)
    Return choices = displaylist
        .Select(Function(x) x.[PROPERTYNAME])
        .ToList
        .Distinct()
End Function
```

I believe this is job for Linq Expressions. But I'm no good at it. So need assistance here.

Thanks!

Comment: Pass the expression as an argument to the function

Comment: I think you could use the [Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the power of the extension methods and the Generic Types to write a generic extension method to obtain distinct result of every List(Of T):

**VB**

```
Dim objects = New List(Of TestObject)()
objects.Add(New TestObject(1, "Test1"))
objects.Add(New TestObject(1, "Test2"))
objects.Add(New TestObject(1, "Test3"))
objects.Add(New TestObject(2, "Test4"))
objects.Add(New TestObject(2, "Test5"))
objects.Add(New TestObject(2, "Test6"))

Dim t As List(Of Integer) = objects.GetDistict(Of Integer, TestObject)("Zone")

Public Class TestObject
    Public Property Zone As Integer
    Public Property Address As String

    Public Sub New(z As Integer, a As String)
        Zone = z
        Address = a
    End Sub
End Class

    Public NotInheritable Class DistinctExtension
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Shared Function GetDistict(Of T, S)(source As List(Of S), name As String) As List(Of T)
        Return source.[Select](Function(x) DirectCast(x.[GetType]().GetProperty(name).GetValue(x), T)).Distinct().ToList()
    End Function

End Class
```

**C#**

```
var objects = new List<TestObject>();
            objects.Add(new TestObject(1,"Test1"));
            objects.Add(new TestObject(1,"Test2"));
            objects.Add(new TestObject(1,"Test3"));
            objects.Add(new TestObject(2,"Test4"));
            objects.Add(new TestObject(2,"Test5"));
            objects.Add(new TestObject(2,"Test6"));

        List<int> t = objects.GetDistict<int, TestObject>("Zone");

public static class DistinctExtension
{
    public static List<T> GetDistict<T,S>(this List<S> source, string name)
    {
        return source.Select(x => (T)x.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(x)).Distinct().ToList();
    }

}

public class TestObject
{
    public int Zone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public TestObject(int zone, string address)
    {
        Zone = zone;
        Address = address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom generic extension method. Also, note that you should call distinct *before* calling *ToList* as this will compile the expression; making the query less efficient.

```vb
Dim result = displaylist.Property("Zone").Distinct().ToList()
```

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function [Property](Of TSource)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), name As String) As IEnumerable(Of Object)
        Dim descriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(TSource)).Find(name, True)
        Return source.Select(Function(item As TSource) descriptor.GetValue(item))
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function [Property](Of TSource, TResult)(source As IEnumerable(Of TSource), name As String) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)
        Dim descriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(TSource)).Find(name, True)
        Return source.Select(Function(item As TSource) CType(descriptor.GetValue(item), TResult))
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: This has good potential for flexibility in my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A concise way to answer your question is to use the brilliant [Dynamic LinQ extension](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) to write :

**C#**

> using System.Linq;
>      using System.Linq.Dynamic;
>
> string FieldName = "Zone";
>
> List<string> Choices = **Displaylist
>          .Select(FieldName)
>          .Cast<string>()
>          .Distinct()
>          .ToList();**